# Is it possible to hide the local network traffic of an application from the system and other applications that may be checking?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sockets, networking

And oppositely, how much information can an application gather about local network traffic?
And how can one restrict such behavior so that any application trying to check it will come up with nothing?

The application uses a socket connection to communicate with another computer on the network.

Also, I'm talking strictly about the Windows platform, 7 and up.

Comment: Unless your application can run at a higher privilidge level than the network service (which I doubt), not, the only thing you can try is using an already running application as disguise and use it's networking capabilities. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You can do some hiding through encryption, but you are always subject to [Traffic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_analysis). It really has nothing to do with Windows or Linux, I suggest you ask on security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @GamErix And unless the application can gain unrestricted access to the network device. And that's pretty much the answer. Want to write it?

Comment: Hm okay. Will do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your application can run at a higher privilidge level than the network service (which I doubt, because this means you can gain unrestricted access to the network device),

**not,**

the only thing you can try is using an already running application as disguise and use it's networking capabilities.